# How can i groupBy using multiple column name?

Tags: sql, group-by

I have a table named as `tags`. `Column` name are `id,tag_name`.
I want to `group by` by using `tag_name` .

That will looks like this,

`{ beauty,general-health,pregnency } as health`.

What will be the sql query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do a subquery

```
   select...
    from (
    select { beauty,general-health,pregnency } as health
    from table) t
    group by health
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from tags  group by tag_name
```